# How to access TABLE C from TABLE A with meantiming values from TABLE B

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

We have table A, B and C

### A

```
+----+-----+
| id | b_1 |
+----+-----+
|  1 |  51 |
|  2 |  52 |
|  3 |  53 |
|  4 |  54 |
+----+-----+
```

### B

```
+----+-----+
| id | c_1 |
+----+-----+
| 51 |  71 |
| 52 |  72 |
| 53 |  73 |
| 54 |  74 |
+----+-----+
```

### C

```
+----+--------+
| id | locked |
+----+--------+
| 71 |      1 |
| 72 |      0 |
| 73 |      0 |
| 74 |      1 |
+----+--------+
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE (SELECT locked FROM C WHERE id = (SELECT c_1 FROM B WHERE id = b_1)) = 0
```

So the result of this *pseudo code* should be all the values of table **A** with the value `locked = 0` in table **C**. But for this I have to *jump* over **B** and get the id pairs.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Use a `JOIN` between all three tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN`s between those tables :

```
select a.*
  from tableA a
  join tableB b on b.id = a.b_1
  join tableC c on c.id = b.c_1
 where c.locked = 0;

id  b_1
2   52
3   53
```

which returns only the column values of `TableA`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cdb5e8486a218955c512f7410ac33c97)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON (B.id = A.b_1)
INNER JOIN C ON (C.id = B.c_1)
WHERE
    c.locked=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON (B.A_id = A.A_id)
JOIN C ON (C.A_id = A.A_id)
```

I used A, B, C, to refer to the tables and table_id to refer to the FK you need to select.

This is just an example you need to adapt that to your case.

Answer (score 1):

Using JOIN should do the thing :

```
select *
  from A
  join B on b.id = a.b_1
  join C on c.id = b.c_1
 where c.locked = '0'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ef50499b7bfed71f7ec9626ad196cba

Use

```
 select A.*
```

if you just want table A elements.